# session destroy after some minutes even though it is set to be infinite

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3

This is how my codeigniter's config.php file look like. The sess_expiration is set to be 0 and it should provide infinite session life. But the user logs out after 5-10 minutes of inactivity.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'MySessionName';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
// $config['sess_save_path'] = sys_get_temp_dir();
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 30000;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

My database.php has cache enabled.

```
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => FALSE,
'cache_on' => TRUE,
'cachedir' => 'application/cache',
```

I wonder which causes the issue. 20-30 people work on this website at all the time. It irritates them when they log-out after every 10 min.

Please suggest me some good solutions. Thank you.

Comment: `0` doesn't provide "infinite session life"... _Setting to 0 (zero) means expire when the browser is closed._

Comment: that is okay sir. if the user doesn't close the browser, it will remain the same. that is enough in my case. 
added the following modification now 
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH.'session/';

Comment: Just leave the `sess_save_path` as it's default value (which is NULL), or make sure the path you supplied is writable.

Comment: yeah the path I mentioned is writable. the folder is filled with lot of tiny files now. Still the issue remains the same. user logs out after some minutes of inactivity.

Comment: will changing sess_regenerate_destroy to TRUE help me ?

Comment: No it won't help, have you tried another browser? maybe yours just deletes the cookies, also _some minutes of inactivity._ how many minutes?

Comment: yes tried with different browsers, os and mobile devices too... 5 min.